# Наследование переменных из модулей

Tags: python

Есть основной код и мой модуль с функциями. Взглянув на весь код ясно, что идет взаимодействие с переменными.
Проблема в том, что выполнив функцию, переменные не глобалятся, как если функции были в коде при помощи global внутри функции.

Я не нашел решения проблемы, перепробовал вставлять глобал в функции и импортировать сами функции.
Если не понятно объяснил цель: Надо чтобы после использования функции из модуля, результат переменных сохранялся в сами переменные (обратка из модуля)

```
import MyFunx
b1 = 100
b2 = 0
a=True
while a:
    print('1 - ( b1 - 5 | b2 + 100 )')
    step = input()
    if  step == '1':
        print('\n===========\n')
        MyFunx.Act(b1,b2)
print('b1: {0} | b2: {1}\n'.format(b1, b2))
```

Его модуль:

```
def Act(b1, b2):
    b1 = b1 + 15
    b2 = b2 - 200
```

Comment: Почему нужно сохранять именно в эти переменные? Это плохая практика, вы связываете функцию с глобальным контекстом. Просто верните из функции два значения:
return b1, b2

Comment: Суть была в том чтобы изменить именно эти переменные, потому что они дальше используются в цикле многократно.
Спасибо за ответ! Вы помогли мне с этой головоломкой :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def Act(b1, b2):
    b1 = b1 + 15
    b2 = b2 - 200
    return b1, b2
```

В модуле, где вызов:

```
import MyFunx

b1 = 100
b2 = 0
a = True

while a:
    print('1 - ( b1 - 5 | b2 + 100 )')
    step = input()
    if  step == '1':
        print('\n===========\n')
        b1, b2 = MyFunx.Act(b1,b2)
```